# Asynchronous tasks to subscribe to orders and fills

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Pretty straightforward question. The methods `SubscribeToOrdersAsync` and `SubscribeToFillsAsync` are pretty similar due to `ConnectionLost` and `ConnectionRestored`.

What would be the best approach to follow the DRY principle? I created the `SubscribeToAsync` method which is my point of view but I would like to know yours.

```cs
using CryptoExchange.Net.Objects;
using CryptoExchange.Net.Sockets;
using FTX.Net.Interfaces.Clients;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace InvEx.FtxExchange;

public class FtxProducer : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FtxProducer> _logger;
    private readonly IFTXSocketClient _socketClient;

    public FtxProducer(ILogger<FtxProducer> logger, IFTXSocketClient socketClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _socketClient = socketClient;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var ordersSub = await SubscribeToOrdersAsync(cancellationToken);
        var fillsSub = await SubscribeToFillsAsync(cancellationToken);

        await SubscribeToAsync(() => _socketClient.Streams.SubscribeToOrderUpdatesAsync(data =>
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Orders: {@Data}", data.Data);
        }, cancellationToken));
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _socketClient.UnsubscribeAllAsync();
    }

    private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToAsync(Func<Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>> func)
    {
        var subscription = await func();

        if (subscription.Success)
        {
            subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
            subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

            return subscription.Data;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToOrdersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var subscription = await _socketClient.Streams
            .SubscribeToOrderUpdatesAsync(data =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Orders: {@Data}", data.Data);
            }, cancellationToken);

        if (subscription.Success)
        {
            subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
            subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

            return subscription.Data;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToFillsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var subscription = await _socketClient.Streams
            .SubscribeToUserTradeUpdatesAsync(data =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Fills: {@Data}", data.Data);
            }, cancellationToken);

        if (subscription.Success)
        {
            subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
            subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

            return subscription.Data;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @nop could you please review my proposed solution? Is it useful or do you have any question regarding that?

Comment: @PeterCsala, hey, sorry, I didn't get notification about that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have not explicitly mentioned it in your question but I assume you are using [this library](https://jkorf.github.io/FTX.Net/ClientInfo/TradeApi/IFTXSocketClientStreams.html).

Your `SubscribeToAsync` is a good starting point. But your to be provided `func` parameters are still have much resemblance as you can see

```
await SubscribeToAsync(() => _socketClient.Streams.SubscribeToOrderUpdatesAsync(data =>
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Orders: {@Data}", data.Data);
}, cancellationToken));

await SubscribeToAsync(() => _socketClient.Streams.SubscribeToUserTradeUpdatesAsync(data =>
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Fills: {@Data}", data.Data);
}, cancellationToken));
```

If you want to move as much logic as possible into your `SubscribeToAsync` then you have to assess the above method calls. What are the differences?

- `SubscribeToOrderUpdatesAsync` vs `SubscribeToUserTradeUpdatesAsync`
- `"Orders:`  vs `"Fills:`

If you could provide these information to the `SubscribeToAsync` methods then you could get rid of the `SubscribeToOrdersAsync` and `SubscribeToFillsAsync` methods entirely.

---

Fortunately you can do that:

```
private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToAsync<T>(
    Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
    string logPrefix, CancellationToken token)
{
    var asyncMethod = methodSelector(_socketClient.Streams);
    var subscription = await asyncMethod(data => _logger.LogInformation(logPrefix +": {@Data}", data.Data), token);

    if (!subscription.Success)
        return null;

    subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
    subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

    return subscription.Data;
}
```

- The `methodSelector` parameter: It select the to be called method from the  `IFTXSocketClientStreams` inteface

  - Since `FTXOrder` and `FTXUserTrade` don't have a common base class that's why you have to make the `SubscribeToAsync` generic
- The `logPrefix` parameter: The prefix of the logging message
- The `token` parameter: The cancellation token

With this in your hand the entire class could be shortened like this:

```
public class FtxProducer : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FtxProducer> _logger;
    private readonly IFTXSocketClient _socketClient;

    public FtxProducer(ILogger<FtxProducer> logger, IFTXSocketClient socketClient)
        => (_logger, _socketClient) = (logger, socketClient);

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SubscribeToAsync<FTXOrder>(stream => stream.SubscribeToOrderUpdatesAsync, "Orders", cancellationToken);
        await SubscribeToAsync<FTXUserTrade>(stream => stream.SubscribeToUserTradeUpdatesAsync, "Fills", cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => _socketClient.UnsubscribeAllAsync();

    private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToAsync<T>(
        Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
        string logPrefix, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var asyncMethod = methodSelector(_socketClient.Streams);
        var subscription = await asyncMethod(data => _logger.LogInformation(logPrefix +": {@Data}", data.Data), token);

        if (!subscription.Success) return null;

        subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
        subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

        return subscription.Data;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> May you just change `_logger.LogInformation(logPrefix +": {@Data}", data.Data)` to something more generic?

```
private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToWithLoggingAsync<T>(
    Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
    string logPrefix, CancellationToken token)
    => await SubscribeToAsync(methodSelector, data => _logger.LogInformation(logPrefix +": {@Data}", data.Data), token);

private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToAsync<T>(
    Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
    Action<DataEvent<T>> handler, CancellationToken token)
{
    var asyncMethod = methodSelector(_socketClient.Streams);
    var subscription = await asyncMethod(handler, token);

    if (!subscription.Success) return null;

    subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
    subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

    return subscription.Data;
}
```

- The `SubscribeToWithLoggingAsync` is a specialized version of the more generic `SubscribeToAsync`

  - It specifies that the `handler` should perform some simple logging
- The `SubscribeToAsync` method's signature looks a bit terrifying now, but it is generic enough to be reused in multiple ways

---

**UPDATE #2**

> `public abstract Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>> SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(string symbol,      Action<DataEvent<FTXStreamTicker>> handler, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))` I wasn't able to call this method.

If you look at the signature of the method then you can see there is an extra input parameter called `symbol`. The `SubscribeToAsync`'s `methodSelector` is unaware of this.

In order to support the call of `SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync` or `SubscribeToTradeUpdatesAsync` like this:

```
await SubscribeWithSymbolToAsync<FTXStreamTicker>(stream => stream.SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync, "Ticker", cancellationToken);
await SubscribeWithSymbolToAsync<IEnumerable<FTXTrade>>(stream => stream.SubscribeToTradeUpdatesAsync, "Trade", cancellationToken);
```

we need the following trick:

```
private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeWithSymbolToAsync<T>(
    Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<string, Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
    string symbol, CancellationToken token)
{
    var asyncMethod = (Action<DataEvent<T>> handler, CancellationToken cToken) =>
        methodSelector(_socketClient.Streams)(symbol, handler, cToken);

    var subscription = await asyncMethod(data => _logger.LogInformation(symbol + ": {@Data}", data.Data), token);

    return SubscribeToEvents(subscription);
}

private async Task<UpdateSubscription?> SubscribeToAsync<T>(
    Func<IFTXSocketClientStreams, Func<Action<DataEvent<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>>>> methodSelector,
    Action<DataEvent<T>> handler, CancellationToken token)
{
    var asyncMethod = methodSelector(_socketClient.Streams);
    var subscription = await asyncMethod(handler, token);

    return SubscribeToEvents(subscription);
}

private UpdateSubscription SubscribeToEvents(CallResult<UpdateSubscription> subscription)
{
    if (!subscription.Success) return null;

    subscription.Data.ConnectionLost += () => _logger.LogError("Connection lost");
    subscription.Data.ConnectionRestored += _ => _logger.LogInformation("Connection restored");

    return subscription.Data;
}
```

- The `SubscribeWithSymbolToAsync` binds the `symbol` formal parameter of the `methodSelector` to the provided `symbol` parameter

  - In other words, we convert a `Func<T1, T2, T3>` to a `Func<T2, T3>` by supplying `T1`
- The `SubscribeWithSymbolToAsync` does not rely on `SubscribeToAsync` so I extract the common part

  - The `SubscribeToEvents` handles the event subscribtions

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like your solution. May you just change `_logger.LogInformation(logPrefix +": {@Data}", data.Data)` to something more generic? Because I would be pushing messages to rabbitmq or kafka. The logger was just an example.

Comment: @nop Thanks, I will amend my post later today to address this concern as well

Comment: @nop Updated, please check it!

Comment: Thank you for the update! `public abstract Task<CallResult<UpdateSubscription>> SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync(
    string symbol, 
    Action<DataEvent<FTXStreamTicker>> handler, 
    CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))` I wasn't able to call this method. I assume it's because of the fact that it has additional parameters. Btw, keep in mind that there are methods with various parameters such as multiple handlers.

Comment: And yeah, that's the library FTX.NET by JKorf

Comment: @nop You can not define a methodSelector which works with any kind of parameters and return type. As I can see this one has an extra symbol parameter.

Comment: @nop You can do currying or use partial applied method to bind the first parameter. If you wish I can show that how to do that.

Comment: That would be nice to if you show

Comment: @nop I've updated my post. *I hope you don't come up with a new requirement :)*

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put and the time you spent, it looks precious!